# SSIS as a Service on a VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I have an Azure-hosted SQL Database.  As is well documented, SSIS is not currently supported on Azure.  There are a number of [articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/01/05/running-ssis-on-azure-vm-iaas-do-more-with-less-money/) about running SSIS and SQL on an Azure VM, but this is prohibitively expensive.

Is it possible to deploy SSIS packages to an Azure VM and have them execute against my Azure SQL database to automate the import of CSV data?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem what I want to achieve is impossible as I would need a full SQl Server licenses in order to run SSIS packages.  This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359061/dtexec-exe-without-full-sql-server) confirms that

> To execute SSIS packages using dtexec or any other method requires a
>   full SQL Server license for the server that you are running them on.
>   Although SQL Server components can be split out, you still need a full
>   license for every server you install them to.